# How can I switch global styles in Angular 5?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, bootstrapping

I have two Angular 5 projects. First is a landing page with login and registration and the second one is a main panel of the app. I have a problem because both of them use different global styles declared in angular.cli.

For instance the landing page uses Bootstrap from node_modules and main panel uses Bootstrap from assets. They are different and overrides each other. Even if I tried to add to every component of these both apps proper CSS they didn't work correctly, because theirs components need in global styles a proper version of node_modules.

So depends from which project I use global styles (landing page or main panel) only this one page is working properly. With the second one there is a problem with styles and a lot of components don't look and work as they should. Node_modules is just an example. There are also other styles declared in angular.cli.

My angular cli with two apps looks in the way shown below. I need to connect them to have only one app. Is there any way to solve this?

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "frontend"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "name":"home",
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index-home.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
        "../node_modules/arrive/src/arrive.js",
        "../node_modules/moment/moment.js",
        "../node_modules/chartist/dist/chartist.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap-notify/bootstrap-notify.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    },
    {
      "name":"landing-page",
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index-landing-page.html",
      "main": "main2.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "assets/landing-page/sass/paper-kit.scss",
        "assets/landing-page/css/demo.css",
        "assets/landing-page/css/nucleo-icons.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
        "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you having two projects? By using the apps section of the `.angular-cli.json` file? And are you defining your global styles in that same file? If so, I believe each different app can have their own global styles by defining their own `styles` property.

Comment: @KevinDoyon Yes, but I want to have one app and I these global styles collide. I am not sure how can I solve this. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need two projects? Why can't you have routes for each of these in a single app?

Comment: @sabithpocker I absolutely don't want to have two projects. My goal is to just connect them into one. But there are problems described in question with global styles declared in angular.cli. I updated my question with angular.cli. Maybe now it will be clearer.